# SASS variables not being overriden

Tags: sass

This is driving me mad.
I have a load of SCSS files and 1 variable file.
I include them in my **core.scss** like this:

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:900,700,500,300);

@import "global/variables";
@import "components";
@import "layout";

*:focus {
    outline: none !important;
}
```

Inside my variables stylesheet, I have this:

```
$font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;

$primary: #000000;
$secondary: #E67F22;
$tertiary: #F1C40F;

$green: #27AE61;
$blue: #297FB8;
$silver: #B2BABB;
$white-sky: #F5F7F8;
$grey: #F0F2F2;
$clouds: #E5E8E8;
$midnight-blue: #2D3E50;
$wet-asphalt: #34495E;
$concrete: #7E8C8D;
```

Now I am creating another style sheet, which I have done like this:

```
$font-family: 'Gill Sans';
$green: '#000000';

@import "../global/variables";
@import "../components";
@import "../layout";

*:focus {
    outline: none !important;
}
```

But neither the font or the colour has changed.
Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are setting your updated variables before your generic ones. So your variables are actually overwritten, but not in the direction you want them to.

You need to do it this way to achieve your goal:

```
@import "../global/variables";

$font-family: 'Gill Sans';
$green: '#000000';

@import "../components";
@import "../layout";


*:focus {
    outline: none !important;
}
```

Or better, to have another file for your customized variables.